# How to build live image from custom compiled kernel? (Live-build)

Tags: debian, livecd

I want to create a final infrastructure to boot a PXE custom kernel image, but through the process I'm stuck creating a middle "live" CD ISO using a previously compiled custom kernel image with the `live-build` tool.

I don't know how/where to specifiy the `lb` config/live build tool to use my own kernel deb package instead the default `amd64-kernel` flavour.

I think that I have to use the `--linux-packages` parameter, but I don't really understand how. I can't find any kind of info or example.
I have read all the man pages and so on, but I'm stuck.

My current `auto/lb` config:

```
*lb config no auto \  
    --architectures amd64 \  
    --distribution stretch \    
    --system live \  
    --chroot-filesystem squashfs \  
    --apt-recommends false \  
    --apt-indices none \  
    --memtest none \  
    --debian-installer false \  
    --interactive shell \  
    --bootloaders syslinux \ 
    --bootappend-live "boot=live components hostname=test username=test sudo" \  
    "${@}"*
```

How can I create a live image with custom compiled kernel?

Comment: I was looking into how to configure live-build and came across both this question and the following page which covers how to include custom kernels. See section 8.2.10, which is just over halfway down the page. https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/customizing-package-installation.en.html#441

Answer (score 0):

Srry i'm late
But for others who are also want to do this...
Well you can put custom compiled kernel debs on config/packages.chroot folder ... And lb build will automatically install them

Answer (score 0):

As Sounak Kar said, you have to put the custom kernel in config/packages.chroot folder.

The name of the kernel must end with "-arch", replacing "arch" by the architecture, for amd64, it may be compiled with the following command, for a 4 threads CPU:

```
make bindeb-pkg -j4 LOCALVERSION="-custom-amd64" KDEB_PKGVERSION="1"
```

You may have to add a hook for the end of chroot building, in order to remove the built-in kernel, and make an initramfs for the custom kernel.

For example an executable file named: `config/hooks/normal/0600-kernel.hook.chroot`

```
#!/bin/sh

set +e

# delete built-in kernel of bookworm:
apt -y remove linux-image-amd64
apt -y remove linux-image-6.0.0-*
apt -y autoremove
apt -y clean

# make initramfs for all installed kernels:
update-initramfs -c -k all

set -e
```

In this script, written to make a bookworm live DVD, you have to replace the names of built-in kernels, that follow `apt -y remove`, in function of those installed by the distribution you are building.